# Why is the array empty after filtering?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I'm trying to filter some objects in an array. But when I do it, I just get an empty array.

Code:

```
let guilds = guildsData.filter((el) => {
    return el.owner == 'true';
});
console.log(guilds);
```

Array:

```
[ 
  { owner: false,
    permissions: 2146958463,
    icon: 'e568d2b87e31358588cb982354628d51',
    id: '267920024570691586',
    name: 'Hydra' },
  { owner: true,
    permissions: 2146958463,
    icon: null,
    id: '269159705794838529',
    name: 'test 2' } ]
```

(I removed most of the objects, but they all look like this)

Comment: because `"true" != true`

Comment: This looks like a truthy/falsy issue, what's the expected type of el.owner? if you are comparing agains the string value `true` then you need to use `el.owner === 'true'` which will compare both the value and the type of `el.owner`. If el.owner is a boolean, then you can just filter using `let guilds = guildsData.filter(x => x.owner);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The string `'true'` is not the same as the boolean constant `true`.

When one side of `==` is boolean and the other is something else, the comparison is done after converting that boolean to number. Thus

```
'true' == true
```

is carried out as

```
'true' == 1
```

Comment: @Kinduser I really have no idea what you mean, and I don't see what that question has to do with this one.

Comment: Thanks, I feel stupid now

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let guilds = guildsData.filter((el) => {
    return el.owner;
});
```

no need to compare `true` to `'true'` (they are not the same anyway).